# Is there a keyboard shortcut to queue a selected song so that iTunes will play it next?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, shortcut-menu

Is there a keyboard shortcut to queue up a selected song to the "Up Next" playlist that was introduced in iTunes 11?

I like that new feature but having to alt-click or select from a panel isn't fast enough to queue up a few songs rapidly.

Comment: tried to get this working, no luck yet. using keyboard preferences to add an application shortcut doesn't work; need to right-click before it does, which makes having a shortcut less than useful

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if there is any way to do that for podcasts, I quite like to have my podcast to play after the current music piece, and not right now… For now, I have to change the type to music (or video clip) add it to the "up next" and change the type back to podcast…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> on Windows) will add the selected song to the Up Next list (in iTunes 11.0, this *does not* work in album view, but does in all other views). However, iTunes will always ask you if you want to clear the previous songs from the list, so an extra keystroke is needed.

There are one or two drawbacks to this method, firstly: It defaults to clear the previous songs so a simple <kbd>enter</kbd> will not suffice and a <kbd>P</kbd> keystroke is needed to add the song while keeping the existing list. Secondly: In addition the added song will default to the top of the 'Up Next' playlist as oppose to when you click to add a song (in this instance the added song will default to the bottom of the list).

I'm only running Windows so I can't say the same (or similar) is true for Macs.

Comment: It is Alt+Enter for the Mac. The dialog asking if you want to clear is a really annoying though and really slows the adding down.

Comment: Alt Enter only seems to work in Songs or Playlist view, if I'm in Album view and looking inside an album, it doesnt work, terrible.

Comment: Seems like that's about as good as gets for right now.  Thanks for the tip.  Out of curiosity, how did you find that out? Is it in the keyboard shortcuts list? Or did you just guess at it?

Comment: Really happy to see these in iTunes at last. This feature has been available in Winamp for ages and I have felt that it is a really bad choice by Apple not to add this choice to iTunes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no clear keyboard command, but if you hold the option key down, when your mouse hovers over a song, a circled plus icon appears to rapidly add songs to the Up Next playlist.

[image]

There is a nice animation where the artwork gets added to the playlist icon as it turns blue to indicate songs are in queue. Since the still picture doesn't show this very well, here is [a short clip](http://cl.ly/LGIm) of it in action.

Comment: While not a hot key, this works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Opt-Enter</kbd> to add it to play next. i was soooo happy when i figured this out.

Comment: This works to add one song, but adding the second song pops up a [dialog like this](http://cl.ly/LHxh). Can you elaborate on how to add more than one song (one by one or in order with several songs) using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I read on the Help menu that you can also drag the song to the top area of iTunes (where it tells you the current song) to add it to the queue. Not as fast as a keyboard shortcut but helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the song, you can select "Play Next."  That adds it to the playlist and plays it next.

Specifically to your question, you could go into Accessibility, Keyboard, Keyboard Shortcuts, Application Shortcuts, and see if you can muck about with the proper menu commands and assign them to the shortcut.  I tried a simple "Play Next" but couldn't get the key-combination right.  But I've got 3 million key combinations set up so I'm sure it was me :)

---

Edited just moments after.  You might also take a look at Automator if you want to expand potential functions via keyboard shortcut.  If you create a Service, you can select "Music" from the Library and there are many things you can do from there.  It takes file input, text input, etc.  You could, for instance, be in terminal, highlight a song, and play it.  Stuff like that.  Thought I would add that in case you are looking for super-cool stuff to do.