# Is there any keyboard shortcut for Play Later option in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, applescript

If you right click a song in iTunes you will be able to select the Play Later option that adds it to queue.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

[image]

I was also not able to find this command in Apple Script's dictionary for iTunes.

*(I just switched from Winamp on Windows, where I had to simply type J to add the currently highlighted song to queue)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create an **app shortcut** via *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts*, which allows you to assign a hotkey to the menu item as I've done here:

[image]

Now the shortcut is displayed next to the menu item when you right-click on a song, which you won't need to do anymore because you can simply use your hotkey:

[image]

Comment: This is great, it actually works. Do you know if this works for any app? I've tested in Chrome and the shortcut worked, but it was not displayed next to the context menu entry. I'm wondering if it's something enforced by the app developers or something that MacOS enforces to the context menus that it renders.

Comment: It does work in any application, yes.  If there's a menu item that exists in the main menu bar accessible from the top of the screen, then you can create or modify its shortcut.  Sadly, if it's **only** in a context menu and not in the main menu, you can't.  Whether or not the appearance of the shortcut in a context menu is controlled by the developer or by Apple, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73218/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-queue-a-selected-song-so-that-itunes-will-play-i) is the closest thing to what you're looking for.

I don't think you can add a song to the play later list with a keyboard shortcut without clearing the rest of the list(which is what appears to happen when you use Option + Enter).

Comment: Yes, I tried the Option + Enter shortcut but it acted in a weird way (first poping up for confirmation and then pausing the current song and after unpause clearing the queue, despite choosing not to do so).